# Two identical answers, one deleted by a mod, one left untouched

Tags: discussion

Can anyone explain why my answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10718042/void-0-parsed-to-double-is-not-0

was deleted by a diamond mod, but another identical answer (that by Millthorn) was not touched? If anything I feel that the entire question should have been deleted. That would have made sense to me.

Note that I am not complaining about my treatment, I'd just like to understand the process and the reasoning.

Comment: Strange, though as a non-question that will end up being closed and deleted, this is moot.

Comment: @Oded I agree it is moot in this case, but imagine that the question was answerable. Why pick on one answer and not another. If that were to happen on a real question it would most definitely not be moot.

Comment: I agree with you on that point (so upvoted). Hope @casperOne will see and answer. He might have been acting on a flag and didn't notice the other answer.

Comment: btw the question is now closed, and (probably) will be deleted soon.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You said as much that what you wrote wasn't an answer, so it got deleted.

Your answer was flagged while the other wasn't, simple as that.

I've deleted the other answer, since you brought it up here and it's a repeat of the same thing.

The question itself is too localized based on what the two "answers" found.

Comment: Thanks. In my opinion, if you were able to discern that my answer was worth deleting, you would also have had to have realised that the question was the fundamental problem. So why not delete the question? And I think "not a real question" is the correct close reason, FWIW.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - if Casper was processing the flag via the queue he wouldn't have seen the other answer.

Comment: @ChrisF Is that so? How can a flagged answer be judged without reading the question and indeed looking at the other activity? Do mods really operate in such context free isolation?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan What ChrisF said.  Looking at your answer alone in the flag queue, and based on what you said, it's an easy enough determination to make that your answer was not an answer and could be deleted.  Looking at the question was not required.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan On an aside, comments about downvoting are considered noise and deleted on-sight.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - only the flagged post is presented in the queue. Most of the time it's fairly clear cut whether the flag is valid or not. You can view the post in context when required, but most of the time it's not necessary.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Christian said to you in a comment that your answer was not an answer, but a comment.  You replied (emphasis mine) "It doesn't fit in a comment. **I mean I agree with you**..."

Comment: I think that's a short-sighted view. I'd prefer for moderation to be more pro-active than that. Poor questions are much more likely to lead to answers with flags. You read my comment to the answer that stated that the question was not answerable. Just reading the answer would have been enough to discern that there was a problem with the question. I'm surprised that mods delete answers without reviewing the context, but then I'm not a mod and so can't really understand all the issues. So if it's more complex than I understand, sorry.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I can't speak as to whether or not you can comprehend moderation, sorry.  That said, moderation happens on all different levels (not just mods, but community-collaborated moderation as well).  Ultimately, the question was closed, so the desired end result was achieved.  I'm not sure that there's still an issue? The desired end result was achieved, the system works.

Comment: No it's fine. The person who asked the question has now got an explanation for the conundrum, and I'm sure that the two non-answers were helpful. My opening sentence "I don't believe that's the code you are running" proved to be correct.